# How to read xml parts without loading whole XML to the memory

Tags: java, xml, parsing, stax

I have this simplified xml file, in production it will be large one. I have to read info element (id, sender, recipient) and I am doing it successfully using stream API with XMLEventReader, XMLEvent jdk classes. I am also reading car data like owner, I have to save owner to database, similar to info data. But there is more about car data..

Second part of my task is to take each car node and save it to database as CLOB, one record per car. With XMLEventReader I am not able to do it because I don't have whole xml context and current car XMLEvent does not have something like toString method serializing the whole xml part to text. I would also not like to recreate XML structure by myself. I am wondering how to do that in most efficient way and not load the whole XML into memory. Maybe reading info should be one part and second part of the parser would be to peek specific nodes and cut them out from stream somehow even without reading the car data itself, and save each car to database ? Is it possible somehow in Java 8+ ?

```
 <message>
        <info>
            <id>123</id>
            <sender>
               <name>dorothy</name>
            </sender>
            <recipient>
               <name>dorothy</name>
            </recipient>
        </info>
        <car>
            <owner>adam1</owner>
        </car>
        <car>
            <owner>adam2</owner>
        </car>
        <car>
            <owner>adam3</owner>
        </car>
        
    </message>
</root>
```

EDIT:

I am able to divide xml into parts:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(entry.toFile());

        XMLStreamReader xmlr = xmlif.createXMLStreamReader(fis);

        int eventType = xmlr.getEventType();
        printEventType(eventType);

        while (xmlr.hasNext()) {
            eventType = xmlr.next();
            
            if (xmlr.isStartElement() && xmlr.getLocalName().equals("car")) {

                TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
                File file = new File("out" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".xml");
                t.transform(new StAXSource(xmlr), new StreamResult(file));
                //printAttributes(xmlr);
              //
            } else if (xmlr.isStartElement()){
                printName(xmlr, eventType); //elements of car nodes are not present, propalby consumed by above if statement
            }
```

Comment: [XMLStreamReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html)

Comment: Ok I edited above post, I am able to save each car to separate file for test purpises but I am not able to read car attributes and sub elements / names at the same time, I believe stream can be consumed only once so I cannot do both at the same time. I could read cars to byte arrays and save each byte array to file and stream each byte array to read some properties, some kind of complicated but I think there is no other way ?

Comment: Is doing both at the same time that important ? It's doable, but complexifies everything, and if you're really that performance critical, finding the fastest way will need a few  tries. On the other hand, starting from your code slicing each car you could simply reparse each tiny <car> element once split, and extract data from this slice as if it was a small XML document. Maybe thats fast enough for you, and it is readable.  As a side note, XMLEvent has kind of a toString : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/events/XMLEvent.html#writeAsEncodedUnicode-java.io.Writer-